# Kill chromedriver process in Selenium / Java

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently running multiple Java programs through Jenkins using "Build Periodically" option and uses H 06 * * 1-5 (run it every day between 6 AM and 7 AM from Monday to Friday).

There are certain programs in which i click on Links which opens up a new window. Hence, I use the below Code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='terms']/li[1]/a")).click();
System.out.println("Home Page is loaded Successfully and Terms of Use Link is clicked");
ArrayList<String> window1 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(window1.get(1));
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.close();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.switchTo().window(window1.get(0));
```

Now after the program runs, My other program following this fails because of the ChromeDriver.exe process that is already running.

I tried  using `driver.quit()` instead of `driver.close()` in the code above, but it will close my entire browser.

Note: I have used `driver.quit()` at the end of my program which doesn't help me getting rid of the running Chromedriver.exe instance opened when i switched window.

Please suggest me a a good way to handle this issue. I have been looking for this solution in JAVA. But mostly i see answers for C#.

Thanks

Comment: Can you summarize your exact manual steps you are trying to automate? If you are closing the browser with `driver.close();` how would you `driver.switchTo().window(window1.get(0));`. Instead close the window handles.

Comment: Hi, I click on a link "Terms of Use" from my home page. This opens up a new window. So I switch to the newly opened window to check a static text from that window. Once that is done. I close that window and switch back to the original Home Page Window. So when I used driver.close(), the newly opened window closes, however, the chromedriver.exe instance stays. This creates issues when my next scheduled program runs.

Comment: so close will close the window currently active and quite will kill chromedriver. When you program finishes that is why you need to use quit to close Chrome and the driver

Comment: I do use driver.quit() at the  very end of every program. I run around 20 programs every morning using Jenkins between 6 AM and 7 Am and spread the load equally. But every day some or the other program fails and when i login back I am able to see multiple ChromeDriver instances running in the task manager which i assume is causing other programs (programs that follow) to fail. I also sometimes see that Chrome Fails and display an error to close the program or report it to google.

Comment: Do you need both of your programs to use the same browser session?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `driver.close()` on the particular page, let it be and use the code below in driver factory:

```
//This closes the browser after each test class 

@AfterClass
public void tearDown()
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

It should help.

Comment: I tried using driver.quit instead of driver.close(). However, the problem is it closes everything the program had opened and stops executing all the code that is below. 


If i had to go to 1.Terms of Use 2.Privacy Policy 3.Copyright Information from Home Page. and when i click on the Terms of Use Link and open a new window, When I use driver.quit() instead of driver.close(), My original Home Page screen is also closed and the program stops executing there. I need to continue with my execution and have to proceed on click the "Privacy Policy" and "Copyright Info" Page

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly new and still learning. I noticed quite recently my available memory was running low. Only then I found out that there were lots of instances of chromedriver.exe (and geckodriver.exe for FF) under processes. I use this to kill my ChromeDriver.exe instance.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM ChromeDriver.exe");
```

It works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are clicking on a link which opens a new window, initially we have to store the `WindowHandle` of the parent window which we will use later to traverse back to the parent window. On clicking on the link `Terms of Use` once the new window opens we will shift `Selenium`'s focus to the new window, perform our tasks there and finally close it. Then we have to shift `Selenium`'s focus back to the parent window through the parent window handle as follows:

```
    driver.navigate().to("someurl.com");
    String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("Parent Window ID is : "+parent);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("Link_of_Terms_of_Use_opens_New_Window")).click();
    System.out.println("Home Page is loaded Successfully and Terms of Use Link is clicked");
    Set<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    int count = allWindows.size();
    System.out.println("Total Windows : "+count);
    for(String child:allWindows)
    {
        if(!parent.equalsIgnoreCase(child))
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(child);
            System.out.println("Child Window Title is: "+driver.getTitle());
            //perform all your tasks in the new window here
            driver.close();
        }
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(parent);
    System.out.println("Parent Window Title is: "+driver.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 1):

use `taskkill` in the `finally` block like shown below. It will kill the task `chromedriver.exe`:

```
finally {
    if(System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
            Process process = Runtime. getRuntime(). exec("taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe /T");
            process.destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You answered this question twice, with almost the same answer. Please use the edit link in the bottom left of your answer instead of duplicating your answer. This avoids cluttering the answers and enables others to find the solution more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause could be in the other place. Such issues usually happen in case of unexpected exceptions thrown, which prevent your framework from quitting the session cleanly.

As we can't see the entire picture of how you're managing WebDriver sessions, it'll be just a guessing game.

Driver itself could be killed via command line, e.g. `taskkill` (or whatever OS you're using), which could be executed via e.g. https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec library. But it'd be just a workaround, which will hide a potential weakness of your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

`taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq chromedriver.exe" /F` could do the magic for you